# Add GPS to Your Raspberry Pi Project with Google Maps Pubnub

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pubnub, raspberry-pi4

(I'm following this tutorial : https://www.pubnub.com/blog/raspberry-pi-gps-lte-google-maps-api/ and I use a Raspberry pi 4 model B connected trough wifi )

I carefully followed all steps carefully untill I tried to run the modified gps_simpletest.py file. When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 323, in _rec                                                                                                         onfigure_port
    orig_attr = termios.tcgetattr(self.fd)
termios.error: (5, 'Input/output error')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps_simpletest.py", line 21, in <module>
    uart = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=10)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __ini                                                                                                         t__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 272, in open
    self._reconfigure_port(force_update=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 326, in _rec                                                                                                         onfigure_port
    raise SerialException("Could not configure port: {}".format(msg))
serial.seria
```

I'm pretty sure I installed all modules, libraries, ....
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I know you provided link to blog but would be helpful if you provide sample code in your post that the error is referencing. Show some evidence that you did some debugging into the code, if possible.

Comment: Did you repost this question with a different title as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906160/set-interval-on-pubnub-data - if so, delete this one as I answered over there. Or is this resolved now? If resolved, please add your solution as an answer.